# Looking to create a 3 image hexagon grid like this

Tags: html, css

I just finished some courses in HTML and CSS, but I am clueless about how to create hexagons. I'm looking to create something like this using HTML and CSS: [image: 3 hexagons with images]

This is what it looks like:

Thank you,Robert.
ps. I scored the web and stackoverflow, but did not find anything close.
     All I found were big-huge hexagon grids, but any attempt to adjust resulted in loss of structure.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this. Just see what I did with the middle and then apply that to the rest.  Check out https://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html

```css
.content {

  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  z-index: 1;
  } 


.hex {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
}
.hex .top {
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}
.hex .middle {
    width: 96px;
    height: 60px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 4px solid #6C6;
}
.hex .bottom {
    width: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid #6C6;
    border-left: 52px solid transparent;
    border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}
.hex-row {
    clear: left;
}
.hex-row.even {
    margin-left: 53px;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/>
<div class="content">
<div class="hex-row">
        <div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div>
        <div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div>
        <div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great share Mike, but maybe my description of what I needed was worded incorrectly. I apologize, but thank you for your time. I have edited the question, hopefully it's much clearer.

Comment: While I sincerely appreciate Mike's help, not sure why question says closed. The solution is not what I am looking for. I would like to see a code for:a. 3 hexagons with background images as seen in the above configuration. b. the hexagon is a 3grid, obviously, but with a white border.thanks.Robert.